# Custom TaskScheduler to start task by DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, task-parallel-library

I´m currently investigating the namespace System.Threading.Tasks and the abstract base class [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx). I also found the [ParallelExtensionsExtra](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples) with some custom schedulers inherited from TaskScheduler.

But i need a TaskScheduler that allows me to specify a DateTime, when to execute a task. Can anybody provide such a class or found it anywhere on the internet and share a link.

If not how could i implement such a TaskScheduler on my own (with TaskScheduler as base class)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Threading.Task.TaskScheduler` is part of [parallel library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx) introduced with .NET 4 - its about executing tasks concurrently (parallel). The scheduling is related to scheduling work on threads/cores rather than over some time horizon/period. Are you sure this is what you are looking for?

Windows have scheduled tasks that allows you to schedule some work on specific date/time and/or with specific periodicity/frequency. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx) that provides wrapper in .NET to use this functionality. Perhaps this will fit your requirement.

Comment: I think you are right. I tried diffrent approaches (Windows Task Scheduler, Quartz.NET) and finally selected Quartz to execute Tasks at specified dates.